# How is the remove method for ArrayList in Java implemented?

Tags: java, arraylist

Let's say I was trying to implement Java's `ArrayList` from scratch. I understand that I would use the data structure known as an array, have to expand its capacity when needed, and keep track of things such as size (number of items in array) and data (the contents of the array).

Because of this size instance variable, when we remove something from the `ArrayList`, for example removing 4 from `2, 3, 4, 5`, we will be left with `2, 3, 5, [empty space]`, correct? From what I know we will be setting values equal to the next element over, so not actually downsizing the array, only expanding it if we need to.

If my question is unclear, I am just looking for the `remove(Object element)` implementation for `ArrayList`.

I wish I had a diagram for this explanation. If anything else is needed please ask. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar doubt in **C** lang when i was preparing for my GATE(Graduate Aptitude Test in Engineering) exam in 2016.

Well, I had enhanced my coding skills from that time and now i do code in Java.

According to [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28int%29) API

> Removes the element at the specified position in this list (optional
>   operation). Shifts any subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one
>   from their indices). Returns the element that was removed from the
>   list.

The `ArrayList` class is an array-based implementation of the `List` interface. Specifically, all elements of an `ArrayList` are stored in a Java array.

The implementation of `Arraylist.remove(E)` is as follows:

```
public E remove(int index) {
    rangeCheck(index);

    modCount++;
    E oldValue = elementData(index);

    int numMoved = size - index - 1;
    if (numMoved > 0)
        System.arraycopy(elementData, index+1, elementData, index,
                         numMoved);
    elementData[--size] = null; // Let gc(garbage collector) do its work

    return oldValue;
}
```

Where `elementData` is the backing element array.

In words, it's not so much a shift, as it is a copy of elements, minus the element missing.

Given `elementData` with 4 elemetns

```
[ 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 ]
```

Now removing element at index 2

resulting in
[ 2 | 3 | 5 | null ]

`ArrayList.get(2)` would result in **5**

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy and explain why `ArrayList` shold not be used when it's planned to remove not last elements.

There're 2 parts of `ArrayList`: *internal array* (default size is 10 - `ArrayList.DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10`) and *size* value (default value is `0`).

**Note 1.** When you can predict maximum size of `ArrayList`, do initialize internal array to this size.

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();    // size = 0, internal array Object[] elementData = new Object[10];
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>(66);  // size = 0, internal array Object[] elementData = new Object[66];
```

**Add element to the end**

1. In case of `size == elementData.length` -> create new `elementData` with bigger size and copy all existed data to this new array
2. Add new elements
3. `size++` (there're many `null` elements at the end in the array)

**Remove element from the end**

1. Remove element (if `size > 0`)
2. `size--`

**Remove element from the start or middle**

1. Remove elements
2. Shift all next elements 1 position right
3. `size--`

As you can see, that there's no direct correlation between `ArrayList` size and length of internal array `elementData`.

**Demo:**

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(4);  // [ null | null | null | null ], size = 0

list.add("2");  // [ "2" | null | null | null ], size = 1
list.add("3");  // [ "2" | "3" | null | null ], size = 2
list.add("4");  // [ "2" | "3" | "4" | null ], size = 3
list.add("5");  // [ "2" | "3" | "4" | "5" ], size = 4

list.remove(3);  // [ "2" | "3" | "5" | null ], size = 3
list.remove(1);  // [ "3" | "5" | null | null ], size = 2
```